# Repeating an image based on random integers

Tags: java, java-2d

I created a background using a relatively bland texture (it repeats well, so that's a bonus). However, on top of that, I am trying to add two images in random positions, each five times. So I tried that out with this -

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class RepeatDiagonals {

    public static Image whiteOverlayStreak;
    public static Image blackOverlayStreak;
    public static JFrame framePanel;
    public static DiagonalImages diagTest;

    public static void createAndInitGUI() {
        diagTest = new DiagonalImages();

        framePanel = new JFrame("Diagonal Testing");
        framePanel.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        framePanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1020, 720));
        framePanel.add(diagTest);
        framePanel.pack();
        framePanel.setVisible(true);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

                createAndInitGUI();

            } // public void run() Closing
        }); // SwingUtilities Closing
    }
}


// TODO Add in constructor for better image import
class DiagonalImages extends JPanel {

    public static final String IMAGE_PATH_WHITESTREAK = "imageFolder/whiteBackgroundStreakOverlay.png";
    public static final String IMAGE_PATH_BLACKSTREAK = "imageFolder/blackBackgroundStreakOverlay.png";
    public static Image whiteOverlayStreak;
    public static Image blackOverlayStreak;
    public static Image overlayStreak;

    DiagonalImages() {
        loadImages();
        setVisible(true);
        setOpaque(false);
    };

    public void loadImages() {
        try {
            whiteOverlayStreak = ImageIO.read(new File(IMAGE_PATH_WHITESTREAK));
            blackOverlayStreak = ImageIO.read(new File(IMAGE_PATH_BLACKSTREAK));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

        Dimension size = this.getSize();
        Insets insets = this.getInsets();

        int w = size.width - insets.left - insets.right;
        int h = size.height - insets.top - insets.bottom;

        Random randomInteger = new Random();
        randomInteger.nextInt(900);


        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {

            int x = randomInteger.nextInt() % w;
            int y = randomInteger.nextInt() % h;

            g2d.drawImage(blackOverlayStreak, x, y, null);
        }

        for (int i2 = 0; i2 < 5; i2++){
            int x2 = randomInteger.nextInt() % w;
            int y2 = randomInteger.nextInt() % h;

            g2d.drawImage(whiteOverlayStreak, x2, y2, null);
        }
    }
}
```

The relevant part of the main code:

```
// Makes the Initial BorderLayout 
        allContent = new ImagePanel(image);
        allContent.setLayout(new BorderLayout());   
        allContent.add(new DiagonalImages());
        allContent.add(tabbedPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        allContent.add(logoImage, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        allContent.setVisible(true);
        allContent.setOpaque(false);

        // Add ScrollPane
        scrollPane = new JScrollPane(allContent);
        scrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
        scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        scrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar().setUnitIncrement(10);
        scrollPane.setOpaque(false);
        scrollPane.getViewport().setOpaque(false);
        scrollPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(0, 0, 0, 0));
        scrollPane.setWheelScrollingEnabled(true);

        // JFrame programFrame Constructors
        programFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        programFrame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        programFrame.add(scrollPane);
        programFrame.pack();
        programFrame.setVisible(true);
        programFrame.setResizable(true);
        programFrame.setSize(1280, 720);
        programFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
```

And here's the ImagePanel I have:

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

class ImagePanel extends JPanel {
    private Image image;
    private boolean tile;

    ImagePanel(Image image) {
        this.image = image;
        this.tile = false;
    };

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        int iw = image.getWidth(this);
        int ih = image.getHeight(this);
        if (iw > 0 && ih > 0) {
            for (int x = 0; x < getWidth(); x += iw) {
                for (int y = 0; y < getHeight(); y += ih) {
                    g.drawImage(image, x, y, iw, ih, this);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for the (future) help!

EDIT: Made a small change based on the answer given, and it's still not working. 
Okay, so the problem is that the image that's supposed to be repeated isn't actually even showing up.

EDIT2: Rewrote my entire code for this, and it's still not working. Even setting the background color isn't working, which leads me to believe it's a problem with my paintComponent.

EDIT3: paintComponent is working thanks to help. My final problem is getting it to work correctly in my main method.

Comment: "What am I doing wrong?" you have not told us what is *going* wrong with your program.

Comment: Is the problem that you are not seeing anything? The reason for that is you are using gbi and not g2d, gbi is the graphicsobject of the image.

Comment: @Raedwald Edited with the problem. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First JFrame.setVisible(true); should be done last, after `pack()` which does layouting.

```
    framePanel.pack();

    framePanel.setVisible(true);
```

The images maybe better reside in the application (jar) itself, then you can use `getClass().getResource("...")`.
They should be loaded *outside* paint, say in the constructor. I guess, it was test code.

```
public static Image whiteOverlayStreak;
public static Image blackOverlayStreak;

DiagonalImages() {
    loadImages();
}

private void loadImages() {
    whiteOverlayStreak = new ImageIcon(
            getClass().getResource("/white.jpg")).getImage();
    blackOverlayStreak = new ImageIcon(
            getClass().getResource("/black.jpg")).getImage();
}

@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

        int x = r.nextInt(w);
        int y = r.nextInt(h);
```

Your failure was not using `@Override` because then you would have seen, that you miswrote `Graphics2D g` instead of `Graphics g`. **The function paintComponent never got called!** LoL

---

***Additional question: adding a second panel***

```
    framePanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    framePanel.add(diagTest, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    framePanel.add(otherPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
```

Comment: Haha, I can't believe I made such a stupid mistake. I'll be more careful with stuff like that next time. The images are in a folder next to the .jar file. And finally, I have to add this to another JPanel that I edited. However, when I try this, all I see is the DiagonalImages panel. How do I fix this? (Code posted in my example, I didn't think it was necessary to make another question for this.)

Comment: Extended the answer. I generally use the IDE to generate an overriding method. Even if it is more disruptive in the typing process.

Comment: I think you misunderstood, I'm trying to add the DiagonalImages panel to the other class file. I tried adding another JPanel, and then adding in the panels on that in order, but it doesn't seem to work. Would JLayeredPane be the best for this, because I want the DiagonalImages to be directly over the ImagePanel.

Comment: You are right, JLayeredPane provides layers. That is nicer as using absolute layouting and placing both JPanels at (0. 0) - especially because you do not need to set the sizes as in the absolute layout.

Comment: I haven't ever used JLayeredPane before, so I read up on it, and I tried to use that, but it didn't work... All I got was a blank screen, with no components but the Scrollbar on it...

Answer (score 0):

It wasn't really an SSCCE.

I haven't tested this fully, mainly because I didn't want to have to set up an entire Eclipse project just to point out the obvious mistake.

- Separate the image process from the JPanel.
- Only extend Swing components when you're modifying a component method.

Here's my version of your code. I had to modify your code to read an image to get it to work.  You're going to have to figure out that part of the code yourself.

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

class GUIImages {

    private Image   whiteDiagonal;

    // private Image blackDiagonal;

    public GUIImages() {
        loadImages();
    }

    private void loadImages() {
        try {
            whiteDiagonal = ImageIO.read(new File(
                    "C:/Documents and Settings/BOP00082/" + 
                    "My Documents/My Pictures/Places-icon.png"));

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // whiteDiagonal = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource(
        // "imageFolder/whiteBackgroundStreakOverlay.png")).getImage();
        // blackDiagonal = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource(
        // "imageFolder/blackBackgroundStreakOverlay.png")).getImage();
    }

    public void doDrawing(JPanel panel, Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.drawImage(createDiagonalImage(panel), 0, 0, null);
    }

    private Image createDiagonalImage(JPanel panel) {
        BufferedImage buffImg = new BufferedImage(677, 856,
                BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

        Graphics2D gbi = buffImg.createGraphics();

        Dimension size = panel.getSize();
        Insets insets = panel.getInsets();

        int w = size.width - insets.left - insets.right;
        int h = size.height - insets.top - insets.bottom;

        Random r = new Random();

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

            int x = Math.abs(r.nextInt()) % w;
            int y = Math.abs(r.nextInt()) % h;

            gbi.drawImage(whiteDiagonal, x, y, null);
        }
        gbi.dispose();

        return buffImg;
    }
}

class Surface extends JPanel {

    GUIImages   images;

    public Surface(GUIImages images) {
        this.images = images;
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        images.doDrawing(this, g);
    }
}

public class RepeatDiagonals implements Runnable {

    JFrame  frame;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setTitle("Repeat Diagonals");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.add(new Surface(new GUIImages()));

        frame.setSize(350, 250);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new RepeatDiagonals());
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, just edited my original post a little. The problem is that the image isn't even showing up, all I get is the JFrame, and it's empty.

Comment: Tried your solution, but it still wasn't working, so I went and rewrote my code. It's still not working, to the point where it's not even setting the panel to black, so I've got a hunch it's a problem with my paintComponent.

Do you see any way I can fix that? 

Thanks for all the help so far.